# SSL Connection to docker PHP service through NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx, ssl

I currently have a bunch of Docker-based services that work over SSL, for local development we just use a self-signed cert, but now we are trying to configure the production deployment.

My current testing environment is w10 based, and the containers run inside wsl

For most of the steps we are following [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/nginx-reverse-proxy-docker) and as for normal HTTP traffic is seems to be working, but when I try to request over HTTPS, I'm getting a "500 Internal Server Error", if I do a curl from inside the Linux instance, I can see that I get the site served, but if I try to reach it from elsewhere, I'll get the 500 error.

The question is, can I only configure ssl when working with the final public hosting and reconfigure my domain, or is there a way to test everything locally before moving to prod? and might be any issues with the self-signed cert currently inside the apache image?

Edit: From checking [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxproxy/acme-companion) now I understand that in order to have lets-encrypt working, I need to use the actual final public DNS and hosting, but I'm wondering how could I configure this to work locally, or just drop the ssl part? I remember some requirement on our architecture for it to be used on ssl, but not quite sure right now, and locally, I need devs to be able to run multiple instances without issues

My app docker file is based upon [this
one](https://github.com/modxcms/docker-modx/blob/master/apache/Dockerfile)

and the current docker-compose file is as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./modxServer
    links:
      - 'db:mysql'
    ports:
      - 443
      - 80
    networks:
      - reverse-proxy
      - back
    environment:
      XDEBUG_SESSION: wtf
      MODX_VERSION: 2.8.1
      MODX_CORE_LOCATION: /var/www/coreM0dXF1L3s
      MODX_DB_HOST: 'mysql:3306'
      MODX_DB_PASSWORD: modx
      MODX_DB_USER: modx
      MODX_DB_NAME: modx
      MODX_TABLE_PREFIX: modx_
      MODX_ADMIN_USER: admin
      MODX_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
      MODX_ADMIN_EMAIL: admin@admin.com
      MODX_SERVER_ROUTE: boats.trotalo.com
      VIRTUAL_HOST: boats.trotalo.com
      VIRTUAL_PROTO: https
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 443
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: boats.trotalo.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: camilo.casadiego@trotalo.com
    volumes:
      - '~/development/boatsSupervisionSystem/www:/var/www'
  db:
    image: 'mysql:8.0.22'
    networks:
      - back
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: mysql
      MYSQL_DATABASE: modx
      MYSQL_USER: modx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: modx
    ports:
      - 3306
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - '~/development/boatsSupervisionSystem/mysql:/var/lib/mysql'
networks:
  reverse-proxy:
    external:
      name: reverse-proxy
  back:
    driver: bridge
```

Currently, the only meaningful log I'm getting is this from lets-encrypt

```
021/08/31 00:09:46 [notice] 175#175: signal process started

Creating/renewal boats.trotalo.com certificates... (boats.trotalo.com)

[Tue Aug 31 00:09:46 UTC 2021] Using CA: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

[Tue Aug 31 00:09:46 UTC 2021] Creating domain key

[Tue Aug 31 00:09:47 UTC 2021] The domain key is here: /etc/acme.sh/camilo.casadiego@trotalo.com/boats.trotalo.com/boats.trotalo.com.key

[Tue Aug 31 00:09:47 UTC 2021] Single domain='boats.trotalo.com'

[Tue Aug 31 00:09:47 UTC 2021] Getting domain auth token for each domain

[Tue Aug 31 00:09:49 UTC 2021] Getting webroot for domain='boats.trotalo.com'

[Tue Aug 31 00:09:49 UTC 2021] Verifying: boats.trotalo.com

2021/08/31 00:09:25 Generated '/app/letsencrypt_service_data' from 2 containers

2021/08/31 00:09:25 Running '/app/signal_le_service'

2021/08/31 00:09:25 Watching docker events

2021/08/31 00:09:25 Contents of /app/letsencrypt_service_data did not change. Skipping notification '/app/signal_le_service'

2021/08/31 00:09:37 Received event start for container 7e0b47af1ddc

2021/08/31 00:09:37 Received event start for container 283bb4ebec51

2021/08/31 00:09:42 Debounce minTimer fired

2021/08/31 00:09:42 Generated '/app/letsencrypt_service_data' from 4 containers

2021/08/31 00:09:42 Running '/app/signal_le_service'

[Tue Aug 31 00:09:53 UTC 2021] boats.trotalo.com:Verify error:DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for boats.trotalo.com - check that a DNS record exists for this domain

[Tue Aug 31 00:09:53 UTC 2021] Please check log file for more details: /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end was more of an understanding issue, for local development I don't need Nginx, and there, I can just use self-signed certificates, and for prod, the official Nginx/lets-encrypt image does almost all the magic.

The command I used to launch the nginx containers is:

```
docker run -d \
    --name nginx-letsencrypt \
    --net reverse-proxy \
    --volumes-from nginx-proxy \
    -v $HOME/certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
    nginxproxy/acme-companion
```

And inside each docker-composer.yml file, or as parameters for docker run:

```
VIRTUAL_HOST: mydomain.or.subdomain.com 
      VIRTUAL_PROTO: https
      VIRTUAL_PORT: 443
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: mydomain.or.subdomain.com
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: your.name@mydomain.or.subdomain.com
```